# Aggregate per Group returns Duplicates

Tags: postgresql, performance, query, query-performance

I have the following scenario a user belongs to several Groups. The Groups are organized in a hierachy:

[image]

**I want to aggregate all the Person Information of the Groups the User Belongs to. Eg. Person 1 belongs to Group 7. And Group 7 has connections to the following Groups 1,5,7,8 (complete branch)**

I wrote the following query:

```sql
SELECT person.id, array_agg(info)
FROM person LEFT JOIN person_group 
ON ARRAY[person.id] && path
LEFT JOIN person_information ON
ARRAY[person_information.id] && path
GROUP BY person.id;
```

Problem with this query is that I get duplicated Information:

[image]

I don't want to use `UNIQUE` on the `array_agg(info)` field. Rather I would like write my join so that I only get UNIQUE rows of the Person Information Table.

*How would I do that?*Thank you

Comment: It would be nice if you share your desired output. Thanks.

Comment: And maybe a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)